# Вставить элемент в выделенную ячейку QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5

Как получить выделенные ячейки в таблице, отловить их и вставить туда элемент?
Вставить в ячейку можно вот так:

```
item = QTableWidgetItem()

self.table.setItem(self.table.currentRow(), self.table.currentColumn(), item)
```

Получить выделенные ячейки можно с помощью `self.table.selectedIndexes()`
Как вставить в выделенные ячейки содержимое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `self.table.selectedIndex` возвращает список состоящий из `QModelIndex` для всех выделенных ячеек. Чтобы заполнить все выделенные ячейки проходите в цикле по каждому индексу и при помощи метода `self.table.setItem`.

В целом вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос.

Вот простой пример:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import random


class TableExample(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.table = Qt.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(10)
        self.table.setColumnCount(10)

        self.fillButton = Qt.QPushButton("Fill cells")

        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.fillButton)

        self.fillButton.clicked.connect(self.onFill)

    def onFill(self):
        for index in self.table.selectedIndexes():
            item = Qt.QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setText(str(random.randint(0, 10)))
            self.table.setItem(index.row(), index.column(), item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = TableExample()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! про цикл что то в голову не пришло.